# ButterKnife 8 null pointer exception

Tags: android, butterknife

I have never had a problem using butter knife until now. I'm assuming it has something to do with the jump from version 7 to 8. This keeps throwing a null pointer exception when I try to set the text.  It is inside an activity. Also an @OnClick is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   @BindView(R.id.activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_end)
public EditText mEditEnd;

@BindView(R.id.activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_start)
public EditText mEditStart;

@BindView(R.id.activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_name)
public EditText mEditName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_travel);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    mEditEnd.setText("Hello world");
}
```

EDIT: Here is the XML

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_textview_title"
    android:text="Trip Name"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Label"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_name"
    style="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
    android:inputType="text"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_name"
    android:text="Start date and time"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Label"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_start"
    style="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
    android:inputType="date"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_end"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_start"
    android:text="End date and time"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Label"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/activity_start_travel_edittext_trip_end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/activity_start_travel_textview_trip_end"
    style="@style/AppTheme.EditText"
    android:inputType="datetime"/>
```

Comment: can you add the layout xml?

Comment: Are you using "include"?

Comment: `import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import io.realm.Realm;`

Comment: I mean include a layout in your <include layout="..."> because this could be causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not including any layouts